# Tkinter impossible to use place()

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I just encounter problem. 
I can't use the place method in some part of my app.

for example :

```
root = Tk()
gameFrame = Frame(root)
gameFrame.place(x=125, y=75)
```

in the begining of my app, i create a some Frame, then my "gameFrame" is positioned with the method place, and it works !

but later, i'm in an another function i want to places Canvas manually :

```
canvas = Canvas(gameFrame, width=50, height=50,bd=0)
canvas.create_polygon(25, 0, 50, 15, 50, 35, 25, 50, 0, 35, 0, 15, fill="grey")
canvas.place(x=50+50*i, y=50+50*j)
```

It display nothing, neither an error.
Can someone help me ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you haven't put anything in `gameFrame` with `grid` or `pack`, the frame size will be 1x1. When you use `place`, the frame will not grow or shrink to fit its children. Therefore, even though you're placing the canvas in the frame, the canvas will be invisible because the frame is only one pixel wide and tall.

The best solution is to *not*  use `place`, but instead use `grid` or `pack`. If you insist on using `place`, you need to give `gameFrame` an explicit width and height, or use the `relwidth` and `relheight` attributes to cause it to f ill the root window.

Comment: Thanks you ! (i feel so dumb now)